# MongoDb: What's the best approach to modify a model field from an array of strings to an array of ids that would refer to another model?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql, mern

I have a `Profile` model, that contains this field:

```
  interests: {
    type: [String],
  },
```

My app has been running for a while. So this means for several documents, this field has already been filled with an array of strings.

In order to achieve certain goals, I need to create a model `Interest` with a field `name` and then refer to it in the `Profile` like this:

```
  interests: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "interests",
  }],
```

The field `name` should contain the already existing `string` interests in `Profile.interests`.
This is the approach that I think I will follow:

1. Create `Interest` model.
2. Fill `name` field with the existing `Profile.interests` strings.
   a. When doing this replace `Profile.interests` with the `_ids` of the newly created `Interest` documents.
   b. Make sure `Interest.name` is unique.
   c. Remove spaces.
3. Wherever `interests` in the app are used in the backend, use `populate` to fill them.

This doesn't feel like a safe operation. So I would like to hear your thoughts on it. Is there a better approach? Should I avoid doing this?
Thank you.

Comment: If safety and 0 downtime is above complexity, I would decouple app/schema update and db/data update. If you use separate field for the new interests array, and add transition logic to the application to work with both formats you can gradually update database on the go.

Comment: You mean I should create a new interests2 field, that would be of type array of ids that refer to Interest model first?

Comment: Yes, but only if you have to. If you can afford downtime to switch off the server, upgrade application, update database and run tests to confirm data integrity and consistency during a maintenance window it will be simpler to implement codewise.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Step 1:

1. Create a Model for interests,

- specify your desired fields fir interests schema and set properties for particular fields
- specify collection name in options as per your requirement
- create a model and specify your desired name in model

```
const InterestsSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    { name: { type: String } },
    { collection: "interests" }
);
const Interests = mongoose.model("Interests", InterestsSchema);
```

2. Instead of removing `interests` field add new field `interest` (*you can choose desired field*), for safe side whenever you feel the current update working properly you can remove it, Update profile schema,

- update `interest` field as per your requirement, now newly added field is `interest`

```
  interests: {
    type: [String]
  },
  interest: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "interests"
  }],
```

---

#### Step 2:

Wherever `interests` in the app are used in the backend, use `interest` and populate to fill them.

---

#### Step 3: *(just execute the query)*

Make a collection for interests and store all unique interests string from profile collection, so write a aggregation query to select unique string and store in interests collection, you can execute this query in mongo shell or any editor that you are using after specifying your original profile collection name,

- `$project` to show interests field only because we are going to deconstruct it
- `$unwind` to deconstruct `interests` array
- `$group` by interests and select unique field, and trim white space from `interests` string
- `$project` to show `name` field and if you want to then add your desired fields
- [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) will create a new collection `interests` and write all `interests` with newly generated `_id` field

```
db.getCollection('profile').aggregate([
  { $project: { interests: 1 } },
  { $unwind: "$interests" },
  { $group: { _id: { $trim: { input: "$interests" } } } },
  { $project: { _id: 0, name: "$_id" } },
  { $out: "interests" }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TnLY4NYCUsM)

**You have example input:**

```js
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "interests": ["sports","sing","read"]
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "interests": ["tracking","travel"]
  }
]
```

**After executing above query the output/result in `interests` / new collection would be something like:**

```js
[
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
      "name": "travel"
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
      "name": "sports"
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
      "name": "read"
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000003"),
      "name": "tracking"
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000004"),
      "name": "sing"
    }
  ]
```

---

#### Step 4: *(just execute the query)*

Add new field interest with reference `_id`s from `interests` collection in profile collection, there are sequence to execute queries,

1. find profile query and project only required fields `_id` and `interests` when `interest` (*new field*) field is not exists and iterate loop using `forEach`
2. trim `interests` string iterating loop through map
3. find the `interests` reference `_id` by its `name` field from created `interests` collection
4. update query for add `interest` field that have `_id`s in profile collection

```
db.getCollection('profile').find(
  { interest: { $exists: false } }, 
  { _id: 1, interests: 1 }).forEach(function(profileDoc) {

    // TRIM INTEREST STRING
    var interests = profileDoc.interests.map(function(i){
        return i.trim();
    });

    // FIND INTERESTS IDs
    var interest = [];
    db.getCollection('interests').find(
      { name: { $in: interests } }, 
      { _id: 1 }).forEach(function(interestDoc){
        interest.push(interestDoc._id);
    });

    // UPDATE IDS IN PROFILE DOC
    db.getCollection('profile').updateOne(
        { _id: profileDoc._id },
        { $set: { interest: interest } }
    );

});
```

**You have example input:**

```js
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "interests": ["sports","sing","read"]
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "interests": ["tracking","travel"]
  }
]
```

**After executing above query the result in your profile collection would be something like:**

```js
  [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "interests": ["sports","sing","read"],
      "interest": [
        ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
        ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
        ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000004")
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": 2,
      "interests": ["tracking","travel"],
      "interest": [
        ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
        ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000003")
      ]
    }
  ]
```

---

#### Step 5:

Now you have completed all the steps and you have newly added `interest` field
and also old field `interests` field is still in safe mode, just make sure everything is working properly you can delete old `interests` field,

- remove old field `interests` field from all profiles

```
db.getCollection('profile').updateMany(
  { interests: { $exists: true } }, 
  { $unset: { "interests": 1 } }
);
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NO3rJ-Tslbo)

---

> **Warning:**
>
> - Test this steps in your local/development server before executing in production server.
> - Take backup of your database collections before executing queries.
> - Field and schema names are predicted you can replace with your original name.

Comment: Hello again, I am just curious. Is it possible to copy the data in the new interest field into the old interests field instead of deleting the old interests field? This is in order to retain the logical labeling of  the field as it represents multiple interests rather than just one.

Comment: what is the current situation? do you have both fields `interest` & `intereses` in every documents? are you planing to remove old interests fields data or you have removed that?

Comment: I have both interest and interests and I am using the newly created interest field. But, for the sake of logical coherence, I would like to go back to interests. In other words, copy the data in interest into the old interests fields. 2/ I have interest in every document. But, not interests because it's no longer used. 3/ As I said the old interests field data is now useless since I have it all in interest.

Comment: you can use rename field query from `interest` to `interests`, see [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6NFk49TfH1A), this will replace `interests` by `interest`. and also you have to change field name in code from `interest` to `interests`.